# How to get specific data from session() laravel 6?

Tags: laravel

I need to get specific data from a session I send instead of getting the entire array from the session from the session() method. How do I capture just the "title" from the array?

In a controller:

```
return redirect('bladeFile')->with('search', $search);
```

In the blade file:

```
{{session('search')}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
@if(session()->has('search'))
    {{ session('search')['title'] ?? '' }}
@endif
```

I added `??` so it does not throw an error, but it will be empty in case there is no `title` in the array. If that's an array at all.

-- EDIT

Then you will need to iterate over it:

```
@if(session()->has('search'))
    @foreach(session('search') as $item)
        {{ $item->title ?? '' }} // or {{ $item['title'] ?? '' }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried this but I get an error message "Undefined index: title" back.

Comment: @noahi then it means that your search is not an array. Can you try in your controller `dd($search)` and share the result here?

Comment: It gives me a few arrays:
`Collection {#281 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#283 ▼
      +"id": 4
      +"key": "something"
      +"creatorId": "1"
      +"creatorName": "noah"
      +"title": "Team 11"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    1 => {#282 ▶}
    2 => {#285 ▶}
  ]
}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ session('search.title') }}
```

You can use "dot notation" to get a value from an array index. Assuming you actually have what you think you have in the `search` var.